# I need help finding the natural log of user generated input

Tags: python, math, input, eulers-number

how do I use python to find the natural log of a user's input?

```
import math

def log_e(power_of_e):
    math.log = power_of_e
    exponent = math.log
    return exponent

my_number = float(input('Enter a number and I will give you it\'s natural logarithm:'))
print (log_e(my_number))
```

Comment: Your function never actually calls `math.log()`. Instead it simply returns the value you passed in, clobbering the `math.log()` function in the process. You should look at some basic tutorials on how to call functions.

Comment: I removed your tag as `[logging]` does not mean using logarithm at all. the `[e]` means also something different if you  hover mouse over the tag it will show hint where is described what the tag stands for ....

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def log_e(power_of_e):
    exponent=math.log(power_of_e)
    return exponent

my_number=float(input('Enter a number and I will give you it\'s natural logarithm:'))
print (format(log_e(my_number),'.3f'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`math.log` takes an optional second argument which is the base to use. `math.e` is the constant *e.* Put them together and you get:

```
import math

def log_e(number):
    return math.log(number, math.e)
```